# New activity not starting in Android app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

I am trying to start a new activity on button click. I am doing this at various places in my application. 1st when the user is logging into the system. 
I am using following code for opening new activity:

```
 btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Check if Name text control is not empty
            if (etUserName.getText().length() != 0 && etPassword.getText().toString() != "") {
//code to check login is correct or not
                Context ctx = v.getContext();
                Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, DashboardActivity.class);
                ctx.startActivity(intent);

            } else {
               // tv.setText("Please enter name");
            }
        }
    });
```

This is working fine and DashboardActivity is opened. And on this new screen I have three button, on click of each button a new activity starts.. Code for one of the button is like:

```
btnMyActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMyActivity);
        btnFarmerStatus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFarmerStatus);
        btnMeetings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMeetings);



        btnMyActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Check if Name text control is not empty
                Context ctx =  v.getContext();
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MyactivityActivity.class);
                ctx.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Manifest xml is like:

```
<activity  android:name=".DashboardActivity"  android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity  android:name=".MyactivityActivity"  android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity  android:name=".FarmerstatusActivity"  android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Somehow, the code is same but second-time the new activity is not opening. Infact nothing happens on the screen. What can be wrong in my code?

**Update:**
When DashboardActivity opens logcat shows:

> 08-05 15:33:04.880 3073-3073/com.it.allied.ots_dashboard I/Choreographer: Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   08-05 15:33:05.279 3073-3138/com.it.allied.ots_dashboard E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xabda5950

And Here is the code from Myactivityactivity class

```
public class MyactivityActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_myactivity);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_myactivity);
}
```

}

Comment: Explain  a bit more what **"Somehow, the code is same but second time it is not working."** means. Does the app crash, or nothing happens?

Comment: @Vucko, Nothing happens actually, new activity is not opening. I have also updated question.

Comment: Are the buttons in your second activity static members of the class?

Comment: @Shaishav I dont know what that means exactly, but I am declaring those buttons in DashboardActivity like 'Button btnMyActivity;
    Button btnFarmerStatus;
    Button btnMeetings;'

Comment: Why do you need to use `ctx`? Simply use `this` everywhere instead of `ctx` and don't call `getContext()` in Intent, simply pass `this` there too as the first parameter.

Comment: @user1181942 I know this sounds lame but, if I was writing that code I'd have written: `Intent intent = new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, MyactivityActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);`... can you try with that?

Comment: @Vucko `this` inside anonymous class would refer to the anonymous class only

Comment: Oh, sorry, type `DashboardActivity.this` instead :D or simply call a method there from the surrounding class and in that method use `this`.

Comment: @Vucko, i tried your code, And it is not working. But I saw few thing in logcat. Please check the question updated.

Comment: Post the code from `MyActivityActivity.onCreate()`

Comment: @DavidWasser.. Added in the question..

Answer (score 0):

```
btnMyActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMyActivity);
    btnFarmerStatus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFarmerStatus);
    btnMeetings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMeetings);

    btnMyActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Check if Name text control is not empty
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyactivityActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

I think this will help you.try this.

Comment: What is the name of your secondActivity class, which types of error it show .

Comment: So when I open my application MainActivity is opened. Then I log in to the app and DashboardActivity opens. Then I click on a button to open MyactivityActivity. So when I click on login button i get the error given in question. And then, when I click on button to open MyactivityActivity nothing happens.

Comment: I hope it is not too confusing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that other answers here are not helping you out. Try this :

The other way of creating an Intent is by using the AndroidManifest.xml file.

**Steps:**

1) Open the `AndroidManifest.xml` file and move to :

```
<activity android:name=".MyactivityActivity"> </activity>
```

2) Now use the intent-filter tag like this :

```
<activity android:name=".MyactivityActivity">
    <intent-filter>

    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

3) Change the action name, eg:

```
<action android:name="AnythingOfYourChoice" />
```

(but no space)
The ideal way of writing the action name goes like this :

```
<action android:name="packagename.ActivityName" />
```

4) Change the category name, eg:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

5) Then use the Implicit Intent

```
Intent i = new Intent("packagename.ActivityName");
startActivity(i);
```

This may solve your problem.

Comment: Horrible answer. You don't use implicit `Intent`s to start new activities. And anyway, this won't solve OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

**First Solution :** Define `Context context;` in your activity and `context = this;`in onCreate() Method of your activity.

```
btnMyActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyactivityActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

And

```
 btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Check if Name text control is not empty
            if (etUserName.getText().length() != 0 && !(etPassword.getText().toString().equals(""))) {
//code to check login is correct or not
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DashboardActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            } else {
               // tv.setText("Please enter name");
            }
        }
    });
```

**Second Solution :** if you don't want to use `context` then just replace the `context` in `Intent` with `yourActivity.this`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyactivityActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you check if

```
 btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (etUserName.getText().length() != 0 && !(etPassword.getText().toString().equals(""))) {
            Context ctx = v.getContext();
            Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, DashboardActivity.class);
            ctx.startActivity(intent);

        } else {
           // tv.setText("Please enter name");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I looks like it is issue with Android 6.0. I am trying to update android emulator and it is not working. I am starting a new thread for android emulator issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. What I found was that I had written ListView instead of LinearLayout in the xml file. Always check for the layouts you used in the xml, the issue lies there only.